# Performing a segue navigation controller, but navbar doesn't appear

Tags: ios, swift

I'm segueing to a view linked with a `UINavigationController`, but the `UINavigationBar` doesn't appear.  There is no sign of the `UINavigationController` whatsoever.

My `StoryBoard` looks like this:

[image: UIStoryBoard screenshot]

To perform the segue, I'm using this:

```
 self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "practicemod", sender: self)
```

The preparation function looks like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        var vc = segue.destination as! PracticesView
        vc.practices = sdkPractices
        vc.consumer = sdkConsumer

    }
```

Can someone help me out here? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The start point in your storyboard need to be Navigation Controller.

OR

segue from select view to Navigation Controller to TableView Controller (PracticesView).

This should solve your problem